# Why do quarterbacks lick their hands even when sitting on the sidelines?

Tags: american-football, quarterback

I understand why most QB's lick their hands when they’re on the field. I guess it helps with the grip. But why so many of them keep licking their hands even when they are on the sidelines? Is it a bad habit most of them get in? Do they even lick their hands outside the stadium too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to get a better grip on the ball. Most of them don't lick their hands outside the stadium.